# Getting JSON data in Splunk based on timestamp

Tags: json, database, timestamp, splunk

I have some incident data in splunk which includes a lot of fields number, created_on etc. Now i query data based on time. There are five cases.

1. Last 60 minutes
2. Last 24 hours
3. Last 30 days
4. Last 5 weeks
5. Last 5 months

So every number is created on some specific time which is in created_time.
Now based on the time that i query, what i want is a JSON based on the timestamp.

For example, 
If I select 60 minutes, i want incidents that were created in every minute. 
At 4:01:00, i want the list of incident numbers.
Then the next list at 4:02:00.

Similarly for last 24 hours, 
Between 4:00:00 and 5:00:00 , the list of incident numbers.
And from 5:00:00 and 6:00:00 and so on till next day 4:00:00-5:00:00

Example JSON

```
{"141000213" : {"IN00102", "IIN9239", "IN3u293"},
 "141000234" : {"IN87208"},
 "141000225" : {"IN03002", "IIN9239"}
}
```

Really new to Splunk. If anyone could help me out in this, it would be really helpful.

Comment: What's your raw data source look like?

Comment: 2016-09-28 04:58:14,number="INC0850098", calendar_duration="10:50:00", created_by="guest", created_on="2016-09-27 10:44:11", week="2016-39", updated_on="2016-09-28 04:58:14", resolved_at="2016-09-28 04:31:57",severity="3",priority="1", impact="1", urgency="1"